ros2_control GPIO
I'm not understanding how the GPIO Controller plugin relates to the hardware control plugin, in the Example 10 of the ROS2 Control Demos. To try it out, I created an Arduino UNO program that sends via UART the state of some inputs. Where should I read the UART messages? In the gpio_controller.cpp? Because in the example, the rrbot.cpp logs a simulated state of the inputs, but I can´t make it show the real state of them.
Maybe I'm just confusing what's the role of each plugin in this application.

The hardware component connects to the hardware (via the UART in your case) and exports them as ros2_control state interfaces (of type GPIO). Read the messages in the read() method if you have to poll them. If your hardware streams the data, you might want to implement a different thread and just get the data in the read() method.
The GPIO controller in this example connects to these state interfaces and publishes them as ROS topic.

Perfect, thank you! I also did a more careful reading of the ros2_control documentation and the difference between all the components. That's my fault for wanting to rush things out, now it's all more clear.
